# wp returns "wrong" image ID

Tags: php, wordpress

well,

Code dosent make mistakes so i have something i dont see here...

I have following code on wp page:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'   => 'image',
    'post_parent'      => $pages->ID
);
$images = get_posts($args);
$attachment_id = $images[0]->ID;
$i = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
$p = array_values($i)[0];

if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    the_post_thumbnail($size);
} else {

} ?>
```

It, works, in a way.
it will return a image url and i can use it to show images on page, anyhow the ID it return seems to be somewhat random.

I have the right ID for page to look for images in $pages

i would need to return first image of that page.

I would assume, array[0] would be first image of page, but obviously it is not since it returns very strange pictures from another page, which has nothing to do with this page.

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail` gets the thumbnail for the _current_ post. If you are outside of The Loop, you have to _set_ the current post yourself first - that is what `setup_postdata` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but seems you are doing it wrong. :)

Why can't you use

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) )
```

or

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( int|WP_Post $post = null, string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail' )
```

or

```
get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
```

Comment: based on this i was able to parse my code to work as intended. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try :

```
global $post;
$args = array(
  'post_type'        => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type'   => 'image',
   'post_parent'      => $pages->ID
 );
$images = get_posts($args);
$attachment_id = $images[0]->ID;
$i = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
$p = array_values($i)[0];

if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID )) { 
  the_post_thumbnail($size);
} else {
}
```